# How to fix Thinkpad FnLock LED behavior?

Tags: keyboard, thinkpad, acpi, function-keys

On my A485 running 18.04, I noticed that when I press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, it correctly sets the alternate function key behavior but the FnLock indicator LED on the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key doesn't turn on. **How can I set the FnLock LED to light up on <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>?**

I noticed the intended behavior when enabling the BIOS setting for "Fn Sticky keys", in which the LED correctly turns on when it should.

I tried `acpi_listen`, but it doesn't show any events happening when pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> (with/without Fn sticky keys), even if it does for the other function keys.

Is there a way to get it to light up without having to use `Fn Sticky keys`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, it was a BIOS problem, resolved by updating to the latest BIOS.

I'm not sure if Ubuntu automatically handles checking and updating Thinkpad BIOS versions. If not:

- Check your current bios: `sudo dmidecode -t bios -q`
- Search for new BIOS versions here: https://pcsupport.lenovo.com
  (search for product based on model ID > drivers and software > choose
  firmware/bios update)
- If there is a newer version available, download the .iso image file
- Extract the bios.img from the .iso file e.g. using geteltorito (if
  available on Ubuntu): `geteltorito.pl -o bios.img FIRMWAREUPDATER.iso`
- Create bootable image on USB stick: `sudo dd if=bios.img of=/dev/SDX`
- Reboot, selecting USB stick as bootable device, then follow bios
  updater prompts

Comment: Thanks, this also worked for my T14s with Ubuntu 20.04. Even though the LED is lit, if F1-F12 work, and unlit, if the Fn-Keys work. Any idea how to invert this?